# Virt-Manager and iPhone USB redirection

Tags: 20.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, iphone

I have a Mac virtual machine installed  using QEMU/KVM and I can't redirect my phone to the virtual OS.

It keeps saying:
`spice-client-error-quark: Could not redirect ... at 1-13: Device is in use by another application (0)`

After some googling, I tried `sudo fuser /dev/bus/usb/001/013` to find out which processes were accesing that USB device. I then killed the two pids that showed up in the dock.

I traced one of those pids to be `gvsfd-gphoto2`. So I killed every gvsf/d related processes. Both icons that were previously on my dock because of my phone being connected were gone.

When I try to redirect the USB device using the "Virtual Machine" menu in Virt-Manager, this time it shows no error, but it just wont redirect and my phone gets assigned a new number. Its like it was disconnected and then connected again.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you ever fix this issue? I have the same exact problem as you. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It impossible!

For prevent gvsfd.

```
systemctl --user mask gvfs-daemon.service
systemctl --user stop gvfs-daemon.service
```

Next you will see `apple-mfi-fastcharge` module. Then blacklist it.

But Iphone resets itself while reconnecting to Mac OS.

```
[  804.700882] usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 46 using xhci_hcd
[  804.852888] usb 1-2: device firmware changed
[  804.853033] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 46
[  804.980778] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 47 using xhci_hcd
```

Libusb pipe to guest broken at this point and Iphone reconects to host OS.

### For connecting iphone you need to buy PCI-USB adapter board and pass PCI to guest.